# command line grep finding words with exactly one vowel

Tags: regex, regex-negation, regex-group

how do you list all the lines that contain words which contain one vowel?

I have tried

```
egrep -i '\<.*[aeiou]{1}.*\>' f3.txt
```

but I'm stuck and can't figure it out

Answer (score 0):

You may use

```
grep -i '\<[^[:digit:][:punct:][:space:]aeiou]*[aeiou][^[:digit:][:punct:][:space:]aeiou]*\>' f3.txt
```

**Details**

- `\<` - start of a word
- `[^[:digit:][:punct:][:space:]aeiou]*` - 0 or more chars other than digits, punctuation, whitespace, `a`, `e`, `i`, `o`, `u`
- `[aeiou]` - 1 occurrence of `a`, `e`, `i`, `o` or `u`
- `[^[:digit:][:punct:][:space:]aeiou]*` - 0 or more chars other than digits, punctuation, whitespace, `a`, `e`, `i`, `o`, `u`
- `\>` - end of a word.

See an [online demo](https://ideone.com/CGN9Gc).